# DocumentBuilder gives java.net.MalformedURLException: no !/ in spec

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have a XML file in my resources folder. This is what I have been trying:

First get the file from the resources folder :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ParseXML.class.getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("sample.xml").getFile());
```

Then use the DOM parse to read the file:

```
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
    Document doc =null;             
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = dBuilder.parse(file)

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
```

It keeps giving me "java.net.MalformedURLException: no !/ in spec". What am I doing wrong?

I also tried doing this :

```
fileAsString = IOUtils.toString(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("sample.xml"));
doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileAsString.getBytes("utf-8"))));
```

but error stays the same. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

As requested, including the stack trace :

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no !/ in spec
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.northwestern.XMLParse.ParseXML.main(ParseXML.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: no !/ in spec
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler.parseAbsoluteSpec(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler.parseURL(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace of the exception in your question.

Comment: @VGR I have included the stack trace now. Thanks.

Comment: That stack trace suggests your `sample.xml` file refers to an invalid URL in its DTD.  Can you include the DTD portion of the XML in your question as well?

Comment: Here is the DTD portion:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Policies 
PUBLIC "-//OpenSSO Policy Administration DTD//EN"
"jar://com/sun/identity/policy/policyAdmin.dtd">

Comment: The exception is telling you exactly what’s wrong:  A `jar:` URL must be of the form **jar:** *jar-url* **!/** *jar-entry-path*.  Your DOCTYPE’s system ID is a URL that does not contain `!/`.

Comment: This is the file I have to work with. I am not sure how I can change it. Is it looking for a specific URL? I looked up another file and its DTD portion looks like this too : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Policies
PUBLIC "-//Sun Java System Access Manager 7.1 2006Q3 Admin CLI DTD//EN"
"jar://com/sun/identity/policy/policyAdmin.dtd">

Comment: Simply put, "jar://com/sun/identity/policy/policyAdmin.dtd" is not a valid URL.  You may be able to inhibit dereferencing of the system ID by adding `dbFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);` to your code, before you create a DocumentBuilder.

Comment: I tried that. I added dbFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true); but it still gives the same exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment, the XML file contains this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE Policies PUBLIC "-//OpenSSO Policy Administration DTD//EN" "jar://com/sun/identity/policy/policyAdmin.dtd">
```

The exception occurs because a jar: URL always takes the form `jar:`*jar-url*`!/`*jar-entry-path*, so "jar://com/sun/identity/policy/policyAdmin.dtd" is not a valid URL.  An example of a valid URL would be: jar:http://www.example.com/lib/dtds.jar!/com/sun/identity/policy/policyAdmin.dtd

Of course, the ideal solution would be to fix the XML file, or tell its authors to fix it.  But it sounds like you don’t have that option.

The first thing I would try is to inhibit dereferencing of the system ID by adding `dbFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);` to your code, before you create a DocumentBuilder.  But, as your comment says, that doesn’t seem to work.

The next thing I would try is `dbFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");`, though I suspect the implementation will try to convert the DOCTYPE’s system ID to a URL regardless, which means setAttribute won’t help either.

It’s possible that this was someone’s misguided attempt to specify a classpath resource as a URL (which cannot be done without knowing the location of the containing .jar file).  You might be able to account for their mistake by setting an [EntityResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#setEntityResolver-org.xml.sax.EntityResolver-):

```
dBuilder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicID,
                                     String systemID)
    throws SAXException,
           IOException {

        if (systemID.startsWith("jar:") && !systemID.contains("!/")) {
            String path = systemID.replaceFirst("^jar:/*", "/");
            return new InputSource(ParseXML.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: I was able to make it work by adding dbFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);   .... Thank you for replying though.